# Github API Approved Pull Request

Tags: github, github-api

Github has a [new feature](https://help.github.com/articles/approving-a-pull-request-with-required-reviews/) that users can approve pull requests. Does anyone know where to find the Pull Request approved stats in the Github API?

Comment: Been looking for that myself, no sign of it that info that I can find in the docs or the API preview (https://developer.github.com/v3/previews/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do we know a pull request is approved or rejected using API in github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44159555/how-do-we-know-a-pull-request-is-approved-or-rejected-using-api-in-github)

Comment: If anything that link is a duplicate, since I asked it 6 months before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's now possible to review pull requests using the GitHub API. See [Submit a pull request review](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/#submit-a-pull-request-review) in the API docs.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is currently no support in the API for this. However, it is listed on the near-term [platform roadmap](https://developer.github.com/early-access/platform-roadmap/).