# How do we know a pull request is approved or rejected using API in github?

Tags: github, github-api

I would like to know if there is an function in the Github API which would return the status of a pull request whether its accepted or rejected.  Does such a function exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [get a single PR](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#get-a-pull-request) and check its `state` and `merged` properties. If it's merged, then it's *accepted*. If it's closed and not merged it may be *rejected*.

In fact it may be not *rejected* but closed by a creator. I'm not sure if it's possible to check if it was closed by another user (*rejected*) or by it's creator (*denied*).

Comment: It does offer a `state` however, this can only be `open` or `closed`. Not accepted or rejected or anything inbetween. /e: just saw your edit, that would be a good way to see if it was accepted or reject.

Comment: @nbokmans I've updated the answer. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @nbokmans - Thank you for the quick inputs. Is it possible to tell this by reviews? The link https://help.github.com/articles/approving-a-pull-request-with-required-reviews/ shows that, using reviews the reviewer can request for changes which is giving a indication that the PR is rejected for changes. Is it possible to get this in API?

Comment: @Gowtham yes, there's a API for reviews too. https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/

Answer (score 5):

I was stymied by this problem, too. I had a hard time finding relevant info in the docs.

**Option A**

The tactic I've landed on is to use the [issues search endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search#search-issues-and-pull-requests) with the `review` qualifier in the `q` param.

So, in my case, when I want to see all PRs assigned to me that have not yet been reviewed, I'd hit this endpoint: `https://github.com/api/v3/search/issues?q=is:open+is:pr+review-requested:jordan-bonitatis+review:none`

Other `review` qualifiers include `approved` and `changes_requested` as explained here: https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-pull-request-review-status-and-reviewer

**Option B**

If you want to see the review status for a given PR, instead of getting a list filtered by status like in my example above, you can hit the [pull requests reviews endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#list-reviews-for-a-pull-request): `/repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number/reviews`

This will return a list of reviews for the PR, each of which have a `state` key.

Note that a given PR may have multiple reviews with conflicting states. Like, if teamMemberA approved it but teamMemberB requested changes. You'll have to traverse the entire list and decide how you want to treat it based on all the states.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the repo configuration you can get the answer one way or another. The examples below use the [GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql).

### Case 1: PR reviews are required before merging

You can query `reviewDecision` on the `pullRequest` field for a given repository.

`reviewDecision` is of type [PullRequestReviewDecision](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/enums#pullrequestreviewdecision), an enum with values of `APPROVED`, `CHANGES_REQUESTED`, and `REVIEW_REQUIRED`.

Example query:

```
{
  repository(name: "gatsby", owner: "gatsbyjs") {
    pullRequest(number: 30371) {
      title
      reviewDecision
      url
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "pullRequest": {
        "title": "chore(gatsby): don't terminate dev server if graphql wasn't imported from gatsby",
        "reviewDecision": "APPROVED",
        "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/30371"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Case 2: PR reviews are *not* required before merging

If the repository settings don't specify that reviews are required, `reviewDecision` will be `null` regardless of approvals.

In this case you could iterate over the reviews and check the states. `state` is of type [PullRequestReviewState](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/enums#pullrequestreviewstate), an enum with values of `APPROVED`, `CHANGES_REQUESTED`, `COMMENTED`, `DISMISSED`, and `PENDING`.

Example query:

```
{
  repository(name: "create-react-app", owner: "facebook") {
    pullRequest(number: 10003) {
      title
      reviewDecision
      url
      reviews(first: 100) {
        nodes {
          state
          author {
            login
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "pullRequest": {
        "title": "Update postcss packages",
        "reviewDecision": null,
        "url": "https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/10003",
        "reviews": {
          "nodes": [
            {
              "state": "APPROVED",
              "author": {
                "login": "jasonwilliams"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's possible to filter reviews for approvals: `reviews(first: 100, states: APPROVED)`.

Note that two reviews will be returned if a reviewer gives his approval and subsequently requests changes.

Checking the PR `state` (of type [PullRequestState](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/enums#pullrequeststate)) could be misleading: an admin user may have bypassed the required review process to merge changes.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar requirement - to know if a PR has been approved or not before merging it to master. I added a rule on the repo to ensure that every PR must be approved prior to merging. Then on using the API to get details about the branch there was one field which stated if the branch was clean to merge or blocked . I used this as a way to mange things in my app.

```
 mergeable_state
```

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible using [GraphQL](https://developer.github.com/v4/).

Specifically if the [`mergeStateStatus`](https://developer.github.com/v4/enum/mergestatestatus/) enum is `BLOCKED` then the pull request hasn't been approved and for any other status it would have been approved.

This enum is present in the [PullRequest](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/pullrequest/) object. Do note that at the time of posting this is a [preview feature](https://developer.github.com/v4/previews/#mergeinfopreview---more-detailed-information-about-a-pull-requests-merge-state) and so must have the appropriate header to work. It will also **not** work using the [GraphQL Explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/) while it's in preview.

Answer (score 0):

In the official [Github API Documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/) it shows that there is a GET request you can make that has the field merged_at if it has already been merged. Edit: theres also a merged field as well.

Snippet:
`...
"merge_commit_sha": "e5bd3914e2e596debea16f433f57875b5b90bcd6",
  "merged": false,
  "mergeable": true,
  "merged_by": {
    "login": "octocat",
    "id": 1,
    "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },`

Comment: Is there a way to know who approved the pull request via API?