# How to know if a git pull request is approved via github api

Tags: github, github-api

Based on this api:
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#get-a-pull-request

could I use the state, mergable or rebaseable fields from the response to find out that some reviewer approved my PR.

I'm also specifically looking for usecase where if there is a minimum requirement of ***2 approving reviews***(as shown below in the image) and the pull request only has 1 approval, the state should still be non-approved and should return approved once there are at least 2 approving reviewers. Is there any field that I can use for this usecase?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do we know a pull request is approved or rejected using API in github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44159555/how-do-we-know-a-pull-request-is-approved-or-rejected-using-api-in-github)

Answer (score 5):

Using the GitHub [GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql) you can query `reviewDecision` on the `pullRequest` field for a given repository.

If 2 reviews are required and the PR received exactly 1 approval, `reviewDecision` will have the value `REVIEW_REQUIRED`.

`reviewDecision` is of type [PullRequestReviewDecision](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/enums#pullrequestreviewdecision), an enum with values of `APPROVED`, `CHANGES_REQUESTED`, and `REVIEW_REQUIRED`.

Example query:

```
{
  repository(name: "gatsby", owner: "gatsbyjs") {
    pullRequest(number: 30371) {
      title
      reviewDecision
      state
      reviews(first: 100) {
        nodes {
          state
          author {
            login
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "pullRequest": {
        "title": "chore(gatsby): don't terminate dev server if graphql wasn't imported from gatsby",
        "reviewDecision": "APPROVED",
        "state": "MERGED",
        "reviews": {
          "nodes": [
            {
              "state": "APPROVED",
              "author": {
                "login": "LekoArts"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Depending on your repo settings, it may be a bit convoluted to check if a PR has been approved (for instance `reviewDecision` returns `null` if reviews are not enforced and the PR has received one approval but another review has been requested and is pending). You may need to iterate through the `reviews` to find what you need.

`state` may also be useful. It's of type [PullRequestReviewState](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/enums#pullrequestreviewstate), an enum with values of `APPROVED`, `CHANGES_REQUESTED`, `COMMENTED`, `DISMISSED`, and `PENDING`.

Answer (score 4):

There are two options to do that.

1. You request all the reviews for the PR and maintain logic of approves/review requests by yourself. [Link to docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#list-reviews-for-a-pull-request)
2. Personally I use GitHub hooks and on each review submitted I check whether that was an `APPROVE` and then use [this advanced query syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search#search-issues-and-pull-requests) to [search](https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-pull-request-review-status-and-reviewer) whether this PR was approved or not.

Check [this repository](https://github.com/bmwant/pr-review-notifier) for complete code example (especially [this function](https://github.com/bmwant/pr-review-notifier/blob/master/app.py#L69))

Comment: 2. The search API can return a cached value for the approval status.
If you approve a PR and immediately afterwards use the search to evaluate if it was approved it sometimes returns the previous state.
Do you found a way to handle this case gracefully?